# Trying to send a compressed base64 encoded string from JS to AS3 via Websocket. Problem with uncompressing

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3

Hello and to a very happy and more healthy 2021!

I am setting up a small communication interface between a JS client and a AS3 Server based on the Websockets protocol.
For various reasons I need to compress and base64 encode the payloads.
From AS3 to JS everything works like this (using https://github.com/blooddy/blooddy_crypto to handle the Base64 en/decryption ) :

```
function encodeMessage(message:String):String{
    var rawData:ByteArray=new ByteArray()
    rawData.writeUTFBytes( encodeURIComponent(message) );
    rawData.compress();
    var b64 = Base64.encode(rawData);
    return b64;
};
```

decoding in JS with pako for inflation (https://github.com/nodeca/pako):

```
decodePayload(payload){
    let rawfile = (atob(payload));
    var bytes = [];
    for (var fileidx = 0; fileidx < rawfile.length; fileidx++) {
        var abyte = rawfile.charCodeAt(fileidx) & 0xff;
        bytes.push(abyte);
    }
    var plain = pako.inflate(bytes);
    var enc = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < plain.length; i++) {         
         enc += String.fromCharCode(plain[i]);
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(enc);
}
```

now the other direction creates some problems:
in JS I use:

```
encodeMessage(message){
    let enc = encodeURIComponent(message)
    let zlib = pako.deflate(enc)
    let b64 = btoa(zlib);
    return b64;
}
```

but then I am running into issues on the AS3 side:

```
function decodePayload(payload:String){
    var ba:ByteArray = Base64.decode(payload);
    //this is where the error happens
    ba.uncompress();
   
}
```

the error is a "Error: Error #2058: There was an error decompressing the data."
I suspect that the bytearry i receive from pako.deflate is different from what AS3 is using?

Any pointers welcome!

Comment: If I were up to figuring such a problem, I'd take some simple short text to trace and compare all the stages of encoding in JS vs AS3: original > encodeURI > compress/deflate > base64 to see where it goes different ways.

Comment: Before you do the `ba.uncompress();` part in AS3, trace what are values of `ba[0]` and `ba[1]`?

Comment: That seems to be the issue. The ba traces to:
120,156,203,72,205,201,201,87,53,50,40,207,47,202,73,1,0,33,27,4,196
which is what pako.defalte in JS generates:
Uint8Array(21) [ 120, 156, 203, 72, 205, 201, 201, 87, 53, 50, 40,207,47,202,73,1,0,33,27,4,196 ] 
It seems that the format is a bit different than a AS3 ByteArray?

Comment: A correct Zlib header does begin with `120` followed by `156` so both systems (AS3 and JS) are showing correct numbers for Zlib data. At this point it should work... but somehow you are breaking the laws of the Universe. I will check for you later...

Comment: PS: Try using `ba.inflate();` instead of `ba.uncompress();`. I don't have access to an AS3 compiler right now so cannot test anything today.

Comment: I tried `ba.inflate();`already to no avail. It is basically the same as `ba.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.DEFLATE);`

Comment: Ok. I found the error. Quite a stupid one as it mostly is. The uint8Array needs to be converted to a binary string of course ... see the details in my edited post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution - a stupid little oversight of course ;)

in the encode function in JS the Uint8Array needs to be converted into a BinaryString before it gets Base64 encoded:

```
function encodeMessage(message){
    let enc = encodeURIComponent(message);
    let zlib = pako.deflate(enc);
    let binstring = convertUint8ArrayToBinaryString(zlib); 
    let b64 = btoa(binstring);
    return b64;
};
function convertUint8ArrayToBinaryString(u8Array) {
    
    var i, len = u8Array.length, b_str = "";
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        b_str += String.fromCharCode(u8Array[i]);
    }
    return b_str;
}
```

Then all is well in Roswell.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious if your AS3 code is used in just an SWF file or you have an AIR project.

- If making an AIR project:

Try using `uncompress.apply`... (code not yet tested).

```
//# this is where the error happens
//ba.uncompress();

//# try this..
ba.uncompress.apply(ba, ["deflate"]);
```

- If making an SWF project:

When I needed Deflate algorithm inside an SWF running on browser I used a port of Zlib.

Get **as3zlib** at: https://github.com/BenV/as3zlib (is a port of Zlib for Java).

*note*: While in JS it's better to make local vars rather than global, this a quirk of JavaScript
and actually in most C-like languages (Java, C#, AS3, etc) this is opposite, a global variable is less expensive than constantly making local *vars* every time the function is called.

Here is a usage example:

```
//# import Zlib Class
import Zlib;

//# setup global vars
var zlibdecomp :Zlib;
var ba :ByteArray = new ByteArray;
var decoded_BA :ByteArray = new ByteArray;

//# try Deflate algo...
function decodePayload(payload:String)
{
    zlibdecomp = new Zlib;
    ba.clear(); //in case it already has data from a prev decode
    
    //# all code below can be done in this one line
    //ba = zlibdecomp.uncompress( Base64.decode(payload) );
    
    ba = Base64.decode(payload);
    
    //# this is where the error happens...
    //ba.uncompress();
    
    //# try this...
    decoded_BA = zlibdecomp.uncompress( ba ); //inflate to original big from small/compressed
    //ba = decoded_BA; //if this way of updating is needed
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look into your suggestion later. 
Yes, should have added, it is an AIR project.

Comment: Hello VC.One, 
i have tried the `ba.uncompress.apply(ba, ["deflate"]);` but it generates the same error. 
I also tried to implement your code example `decoded_BA = zlibdecomp.uncompress( ba ); ` but the linked as3zlib library is no structured as per your example. A Zlib Class does not exist, so i cannot instantiate `zlibdecomp = new Zlib;` Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've been diggin deep for the files used in the project. [Download the ZIP](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fden3fs4gdjybk8/Zlib_VC.zip?dl=1) (right-click & save) and put all files in same place as your AS3. You still need that `com/wirelust/AS3Zlib` folder because these `.as` files references that library.

Comment: So. I tried the Zlib but it also generates "unknown compression method" error. 
I will have to look into the Bytearray format that pako generates as I mentioned in the comment above.